# Can I apply for a Canada student visa 15 days before classes start?

Tags: visas, canada, study

Can I apply for my Canada student visa under the Student Direct Stream with only 15 days before the start of my classes?

Actually my Québec Acceptance Certificate (CAQ) had arrived too late and I am applying for Herzing College in Montreal in Québec province. Due to the late arrival of the CAQ, I could not apply for my visa on time.

Comment: You can try. After all how much is the application fee? Risk vs Reward is favorable.